# IMPORTHTML not working for retrieving the table that shows the player rankings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I have used `importhtml` function for google sheets many times and successfully but sometimes I have had no luck in getting it to work.

I am doing this to help track some gaming performances in events.

I would like to retrieve the table that shows the player rankings that I have found on this web page.

[Player Rankings](https://volknn.ru/fire/#/FAME)

I have used `=IMPORTHTML("https://volknn.ru/fire/#/FAME";"table";3)`,
but i only get the tags like shown below.

How can this be dealt with?

```
№               "{{'POINTS_TO' | translate}} {{session.frontier.t/1000}}k 
({{session.globalpointsTank}})"     д           
{{$index + 1}}  {{user.name}}   {{user.position}}   {{user.points}} {{session.globalpointsTank - user.points}}  "{{user.battles > 0 ? user.battles : ""<"" + session.conds.battles}} ({{user.bt_clan}} 
{{'FOR_CLAN' | translate}})"    {{user.wr}} {{user.days}}   "{{multiplier && user.bt_clan >= session.conds.battles ? clan.reward * 
user.bonds : user.bonds}}"
```

Comment: hello @ale13 in the past i have used a formula to do this and then macros to copy paste to another spreadsheet to clean the tables up.... but as far as now for this case i am not able of getting the table with the needed information i need. i don't know if there are some modules in google apps scripts i could use to do this. i have contacted the owner of the website as well to know if he can help me

Comment: Hey @Andrea Tedeschi, did the solution I provided work for your issue? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=IMPORTHTML` function won't work because the website loads the data dynamically so you should be using another method.

A solution would be to use the `IMPORTJSON` [library](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) with Apps Script.

You should be installing by going to `Tools` > `Script Editor` and add the `ImportJSON.gs` file. Now in your spreadsheet you can access the `ImportJSON()` function.

Afterwards, you should just use the following formula in your Spreadsheet:

```
=ImportJSON("https://volknn.ru/fire/classes/getclan.php?front=west&name=FAME&server=ru", "/users")
```

The URL was obtained by using the Google Chrome Console and checking the `Network Tab`, filtering the requests by `XHR` and finding the request which inputs the data into the table.

You can also check this link for more information:

1. [ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON);
2. [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en).